# How to initialise laravel websockets server in AWS?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, websocket

I'm currently developing a laravel project in AWS ec2 and I want to initialise the websockets server automatically in AWS and not in my own computer.

By now I have to enter using the .pem file and start the server with php artisan websockets, but if I turn off the terminal or the computer the websockets don't work in the server.

Is it possibly to configure the ec2 to do it automatically instead on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I answered the problem by myself, I just needed to initialise a supervisor in the server executing the websockets server.